# Not able to parse ExtendedData from KML file using geotools

Tags: kml, java, geotools, parse

We are trying to parse below KML file to retrieve simpleData and geometry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document><Folder><name>super_regi_icsc</name>
<Schema name="super_regi_icsc" id="super_regi_icsc">
    <SimpleField name="RecordID" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Centre_Name" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Address" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="City" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="State" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Format" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Scheme" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Sf" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Yr_Open_Renovate" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Owner_Leasing_Agent" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Notable_Tenants" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Geocode_Address" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Geo_Code_Address" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="status" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Match_Type" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="formatted_address" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Match_To" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="lat" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="lng" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="AddCityState" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#super_regi_icsc">
        <SimpleData name="RecordID">100008</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Centre_Name">West End Mkt</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Address">1 Augusta St</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="City">Greenville</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="State">SC</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Format">Malls</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Scheme">Regional</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Sf">45</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Yr_Open_Renovate"></SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Owner_Leasing_Agent">Joseph Moon</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Notable_Tenants">Kudzu, Emporium</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Geocode_Address"></SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Geo_Code_Address">1 Augusta St, Greenville,  SC</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="status">OK</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Match_Type">street_address</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="formatted_address">1 Augusta Street, Greenville, SC 29601, USA</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Match_To">street_number</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">34.844234900</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lng">-82.404362500</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="AddCityState">1 Augusta St, Greenville, SC</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>-82.4043625,34.8442349,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#super_regi_icsc">
        <SimpleData name="RecordID">100009</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Centre_Name">Bellis Fair Mall</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Address">1 Bellis Fair Pkwy</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="City">Bellingham</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="State">WA</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Format">Malls</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Scheme">Regional</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Sf">770</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Yr_Open_Renovate"></SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Owner_Leasing_Agent">General Growth Properties</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Notable_Tenants">Sears, Regal Cinemas Inc, Macys, Old Navy, Kohls</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Geocode_Address"></SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Geo_Code_Address">1 Bellis Fair Pkwy, Bellingham,  WA</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="status">OK</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Match_Type">street_address</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="formatted_address">1 Bellis Fair Parkway, Bellis Fair Mall, Bellingham, WA 98226, USA</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Match_To">street_number</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lat">48.785697000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="lng">-122.490442000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="AddCityState">1 Bellis Fair Pkwy, Bellingham, WA</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>-122.490442,48.785697,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Folder></Document></kml>
```

Below is the java Code used to parse KML file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.opengis.feature.Property;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.geometry.Geometry;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureImpl;
import org.geotools.kml.KML;
import org.geotools.kml.KMLConfiguration;
//import org.geotools.kml.v22.KML;
//import org.geotools.kml.v22.KMLConfiguration;
import org.geotools.xml.Parser;
import org.geotools.xml.PullParser;
import org.geotools.xml.StreamingParser;
    public class App {
        static String path = "C:/Work/Work/Useful files/sample.kml";
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            File file = new File(path);
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                InputStream iputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
                new App().kmlparser2(iputstream);
                //validateKMLType(file);
                //ParseKML();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (fis != null)
                        fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void kmlparser2(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
            Parser parser = new Parser(new KMLConfiguration()); 
            SimpleFeature f = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse(inputStream); 

            System.out.println(f.getClass().getName()); 
            System.out.println(f.getAttributes()); 

            Collection placemarks = (Collection) f.getAttribute("Feature"); 

            System.out.println(placemarks.getClass().getName()); 
            System.out.println(placemarks); 
            System.out.println(placemarks.size()); 

            SimpleFeature sf = (SimpleFeature)placemarks.iterator().next(); 
            printAttrs(sf.getAttributes(), ""); 
        }

        public static void printAttrs(List<Object> attrs, String tab) { 
            if (attrs == null) return; 
            tab += "  "; 

            for (Object o : attrs) { 
                if (o instanceof SimpleFeature) { 
                    SimpleFeature sf = (SimpleFeature)o; 
                    System.out.println(tab + sf.getName() + " [");
                    System.out.println("geometry : "+sf.getDefaultGeometry());
                    Set<Entry<Object, Object>> attrSet = sf.getUserData().entrySet();
                    System.out.println(attrSet);

                    printAttrs(sf.getAttributes(), tab); 
                    System.out.println(tab + " ]"); 
                } else if (o instanceof  List) { 
                    List list = (List)o; 
                    System.out.println(tab + " ["); 
                    printAttrs(list, tab); 
                    System.out.println(tab + " ]"); 
                } else { 
                    System.out.println(tab + (o==null?"":o.getClass().getSimpleName()));
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

The `attrSet` from `getUserData().entrySet()` is `null`. No luck, even when v22.kml import is used. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use the KML2.2 configuration, the extended data elements show as regular properties for me.

```
package spike;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.collection.ListFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON;
import org.geotools.kml.v22.*;
import org.geotools.xml.PullParser;
import org.opengis.feature.Property;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class KMLReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException, SAXException {
    FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    PullParser parser = new PullParser(new KMLConfiguration(), reader, SimpleFeature.class);

    ArrayList<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleFeature simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
    while (simpleFeature != null) {
      // System.out.println(simpleFeature);
      features.add(simpleFeature);
      simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
    }
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = DataUtilities.collection(features);
    int count = 0;
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = fc.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("feature " + (count++));
        SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
        Collection<Property> attribs = feature.getProperties();
        for (Property p : attribs) {
          if (p.getValue() != null)
            System.out.println(p.getName() + ": \"" + p.getValue()+"\"");
        }
        System.out.println("Extended Data");
        Map<Object, Object> userData = feature.getUserData();
        for (Entry<Object, Object> e : userData.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
        }

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Gives me the following output:

```
feature 0
visibility: "true"
open: "true"
Feature: "[]"
Extended Data
Folder:[]
feature 1
name: "super_regi_icsc"
visibility: "true"
open: "true"
name: "super_regi_icsc"
Feature: "[]"
Extended Data
Folder:[Folder (name=super_regi_icsc)]
feature 2
visibility: "true"
open: "true"
RecordID: "100009"
Centre_Name: "Bellis Fair Mall"
Address: "1 Bellis Fair Pkwy"
City: "Bellingham"
State: "WA"
Format: "Malls"
Scheme: "Regional"
Sf: "770"
Yr_Open_Renovate: ""
Owner_Leasing_Agent: "General Growth Properties"
Notable_Tenants: "Sears, Regal Cinemas Inc, Macys, Old Navy, Kohls"
Geocode_Address: ""
Geo_Code_Address: "1 Bellis Fair Pkwy, Bellingham,  WA"
status: "OK"
Match_Type: "street_address"
formatted_address: "1 Bellis Fair Parkway, Bellis Fair Mall, Bellingham, WA 98226, USA"
Match_To: "street_number"
lat: "48.785698"
lng: "-122.49044"
AddCityState: "1 Bellis Fair Pkwy, Bellingham, WA"
Geometry: "POINT (-122.490442 48.785697)"
Extended Data
Folder:[Folder (name=super_regi_icsc)]
UntypedExtendedData:{}
feature 3
visibility: "true"
open: "true"
RecordID: "100008"
Centre_Name: "West End Mkt"
Address: "1 Augusta St"
City: "Greenville"
State: "SC"
Format: "Malls"
Scheme: "Regional"
Sf: "45"
Yr_Open_Renovate: ""
Owner_Leasing_Agent: "Joseph Moon"
Notable_Tenants: "Kudzu, Emporium"
Geocode_Address: ""
Geo_Code_Address: "1 Augusta St, Greenville,  SC"
status: "OK"
Match_Type: "street_address"
formatted_address: "1 Augusta Street, Greenville, SC 29601, USA"
Match_To: "street_number"
lat: "34.844234"
lng: "-82.404366"
AddCityState: "1 Augusta St, Greenville, SC"
Geometry: "POINT (-82.4043625 34.8442349)"
Extended Data
Folder:[Folder (name=super_regi_icsc)]
UntypedExtendedData:{}
```